# Is the word Physics singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography

Is the word *Physics* singular or plural? Should we write "Physics considers" or "Physics consider"?

Comment: Depends. (Can physics consider anything?)

Comment: It's plural-form (like dog**s** and measle**s**), singular in concept and noncount (cf biology and chemistry; 'mathematics' can arguably be noncount or count – 'different mathematics' = 'different forms of mathematics'; '[three different mathematics in the context of the struggle for](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22different+mathematics+are%22&sca_esv=560657174&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=94LsZM2MIqqwhbIPkP6FkAg&ved=0ahUKEwiN5JeLnv-AAxUqWEEAHRB_AYIQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq) ...') [Uni of Exeter; also the Stanford Uni  article], and takes a singular verb form (physics is my favourite subject).